# Journey builder entry based on changing Campaign Member status?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automation, triggered-send, campaign-member

Trying to figure out how best to automate emails for an event series. There are 2 time zones for the event series.

The plan was 2 separate journeys...

- Send invite to campaign members (Status is Invited)
- Registration form submission (Status change to Registered (time zone a) or Registered (time zone b))
- Registrant enters relevant journey based on campaign member status (?)
- Receives autoresponder
- Receives all reminder emails

There's another complication with the ability to join the series after the first events but I think I can resolve this using decision splits and CreatedDate.

Is there anyway to use this as the journey builder entry? Wanted to avoid having 3 campaigns for this (Invited, Time Zone A Registrants, Time Zone B Registrants)